# Dar la vuelta cuando solo hay una letra

Tags: r, regex

Sunpongamos que tengo este df:

```
x <- data.frame(col=c("100 X", "200 e", "casa", "B", "150 x", "C","234 xll"))
```

```
      col
1   100 X
2   200 e
3    casa
4       B
5   150 x
6       C
7 234 xll
```

Quisiera dejarlo así:

```
      col
1   X-100
2   e-200
3    casa
4       B
5   x-150
6       C
7 234 xll
```

Es decir, letra guión número, pero solo cuando hay una letra. En el último caso 234 xll
hay más de una letra, por lo que no se le da la vuelta.

Hago

```
library("stringr")
x$col1 <- str_replace(c$col,"(\\d{3}\\s)(\\w{1})","\\2-\\1")
```

y obtengo

```
 col         col1
1  100 X     X-100 
2  200 e     e-200 
3   casa      casa
4      B       B
5  150 x      x-150 
6      C       C
7 234 xl      x-234 l
```

Se me cambia la última a x-234 l cuando debería dejarla tal como está.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que ajustar un poco tu patrón

```
str_replace(x$col,"(\\d{3})\\s(\\w$)","\\2-\\1")
```

- En primer lugar no queremos capturar el espacio entre `100 X`, por lo cual lo quitamos del grupo de captura `(\\d{3})\\s`
- Lo siguiente sería esperar un carácter de palabra, pero solo 1, por lo que deberíamos asegurarnos que no haya otro después, o hacer "match" con el fín de la cadena: `(\\w$`)